# Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Functions -- increment counter based on data nodes

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, counter

I'm working on a web application that will visualize data from my Firebase database. But first, I want to be able to "count" the total number of users with a given data so that I can then use that count number in my graphs.

For reference, my database looks like this:

[image]

Because I expect separate totals for the required keys, I'm guessing that I'll need separate counters for each one. I've started writing a cloud function to keep track of when a new user is created:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
export const onMessageCreate = functions.database
.ref('/students/{studentID}')
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    const userData = snapshot.val()

    const afterGrad = userData.afterGrad
    const gender = userData.gender
    const gradDate = userData.gradDate
    const program = userData.program
    const race = userData.race
    const timeToComplete = userData.timeToComplete
})
```

But now, I'm extremely lost at how I should go about creating counters. Would something like this suffice, with an individual counter for each constant?

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
var counterAfterGrad; 

export const onMessageCreate = functions.database
.ref('/students/{studentID}')
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    const userData = snapshot.val()
    const afterGrad = userData.afterGrad
    var counterAfterGrad++
})
```

Or should I be thinking about using a transaction in this case? I'm really not sure of the best way, and would really appreciate some help.

Comment: increase count while creating user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should use a transaction. See the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions and https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#transaction

For counting the overall number of users you could do as follows:

```
export const onMessageCreate = functions.database
.ref('/students/{studentID}')
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    const userData = snapshot.val()
    const afterGrad = userData.afterGrad

    const allUsersCounterRef = admin
      .database()
      .ref('allUsersCounter');

    return allUsersCounterRef
      .transaction(counter_value => {
        return (counter_value || 0) + 1;
      })

})
```

Note that you may have to take into consideration the deletion of a user.

You could very well have several counters, for example by "gender" (male/female) and by "program". You would then use an object in the transaction as follows:

```
exports.onMessageCreate = functions.database
  .ref('/students/{studentID}')
  .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    const userData = snapshot.val();

    const countersRef = admin.database().ref('counters');

    return countersRef.transaction(currentData => {
       currentData[userData.gender] = (currentData[userData.gender] || 0) + 1;
       currentData[userData.program] = (currentData[userData.program] || 0) + 1;
       return currentData;
    });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks! Quick question: is `.ref('genderCounters/' + userData.gender)` assuming that, in my database, I also have a child for genderCounters outside/under my `students` child?

Comment: `.ref('genderCounters/' + userData.gender)` would create a counter for a root node `genderCounters/male` and a counter for a root node `genderCounters/female`. You could use `.ref('students/genderCounters/' + userData.gender)`

Comment: I see. And if I wanted to reference these counters in other parts of my code (for my data visualization), I would simply need to reference the counter value at, for example, `genderCounters/male`?

Comment: Yes indeed, value of `genderCounters/male`

Comment: Could you possibly explain the purpose of `ctrVal` in the above code?

Comment: @gbm0102 Actually there was an error in my first version of the multi-counters code: I was chaining two transactions while the update of all the counters shall be done in ONE transaction! With the new code you will find the number of "males" under the `counters/male` node.